# Where to place fonts folder for use of @font-face?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I would like to use the fonts of my fonts folder, which is in the css folder. The css folder is in the resources folder.

But it doesn’t work whatever the browser used (IE, chrome, firefox). What’ s wrong ?

I am using RichFaces 4.3.6.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'foundrysterling-mediumcyRg';
    src: url('fonts/fostmdcy-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/fostmdcy-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('fonts/fostmdcy-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('fonts/fostmdcy-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/fostmdcy-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/fostmdcy-webfont.svg#foundrysterling-mediumcyRg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As RichFaces is used, the correct syntax for URL was :

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'foundrysterling-mediumcyRg';
src: url('#{resource["css:fonts/fostmdcy-webfont.eot"]}');
src: url('#{resource["css:fonts/fostmdcy-webfont.eot"]}?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('#{resource["css:fonts/fostmdcy-webfont.woff2"]}') format('woff2'),
     url('#{resource["css:fonts/fostmdcy-webfont.woff"]}') format('woff'),
     url('#{resource["css:fonts/fostmdcy-webfont.ttf"]}') format('truetype'),
     url('#{resource["css:fonts/fostmdcy-webfont.svg"]}#foundrysterling-mediumcyRg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
```

}

Thanks for all answers !

Answer (score 1):

case 1 : If the structure is like this

```
/resources
  /css
     style.css
     /fonts
        fontmdcy-webfont.eot
```

then you need to update the url like this

```
url('fonts/fostmdcy-webfont.eot')
```

case 2 : If the structure is like this

```
/resources
  style.css
  /css         
     /fonts
        fontmdcy-webfont.eot
```

then you need to update the url like this

```
url('css/fonts/fostmdcy-webfont.eot')
```

Comment: **url('fonts/fostmdcy-webfont.eot')** This line should be in your style.css

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `./` in front of your path.

Comment: I've tried src: url('./fonts/fostmdcy-webfont.eot'); it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It should work :)

I could not get the font you used, but based on your files, look at my structure :

```
/test-project
    /Deployed Resources
        /webapp
            /WEB-INF
            test.html
        /web-resources
            /images
            /resources
                /css
                    a.css
                    /fonts
                        lobster_1.3-webfont.eot
                        (and svg, ttf, woff, woff2... files)
```

And my test.html file :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/a.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">Test</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In my a.css :

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'foundrysterling-mediumcyRg';
    src: url('fonts/lobster_1.3-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/lobster_1.3-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/lobster_1.3-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
        url('fonts/lobster_1.3-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/lobster_1.3-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/lobster_1.3-webfont.svg#lobster_1.3regular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
#header {
    font-family: foundrysterling-mediumcyRg, sans-serif;
}
```

So, why does it not work on your computer ?

1. Check the spell of the files in your `fonts` folder (uppercase/lowercase).
2. What do you see when you spy on the style in your browser ? Do you see that the `foundrysterling-mediumcyRg` style should be applied ? Isn't it overloaded by another style ?
3. Try to spy the network exchanges in your browser. Is the font file loaded by the browser ? With a status code 200 ? If not OK, what happens when you try `http://localhost:8080/{your app context}/resources/css/fonts/fostmdcy-webfont.woff2` in your browser ?

Comment: Font files are not loaded (404 errors). I have tried with another font, and the following URL in my browser downloads the font file with expected content :    
http://localhost:8080/x/resources/css/fonts/bankgothic-webfont.ttf
Errors seen in console :
GET http://localhost:8080/x/javax.faces.resource/fonts/bankgothic-webfont.woff2 
GET http://localhost:8080/x/javax.faces.resource/fonts/bankgothic-webfont.woff 
GET http://localhost:8080/x/javax.faces.resource/fonts/bankgothic-webfont.ttf  404 (OK)
Are errors due to RichFaces ?

Comment: In a css file, partial paths are relative to the stylesheet location, not to your html document. 
Your css should be available at localhost:8080/x/resources/css/myfile.css, not at  localhost:8080/x/javax.faces.resource/css/myfile.css . If you are in the 1st case, please check again that in your css file urls start with 'fonts/' not '../fonts' or '/fonts' or something else.
In your html code, do you have a <base href="..." /> tag ?

Comment: And if you build your war, are the 'css', 'fonts' directories where they should be ?